# Selecting a row which has the minimum value (of some column) according to the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sap-ase

Imagine the following:

I have a table `Customers`, each customer can have 0 or more `PhoneNumbers`.  The phone numbers are indexed on the `Customers`' `CusId` and its own `ListIx` (so `(CusId, ListIx)`).

I want to select a list of customers along with their *first* (`min(ListIx)`) phone number.

Question, what is the most elegant way to do this?

For instance:

```
select
    c.FirstName, c.LastName, pn.PhoneNo
  from Customers c
    left join PhoneNumbers pn
      on c.CusId = pn.CusId
        and pn.ListIx = (select min(ListIx) from PhoneNumbers where CusId = c.CusId)
```

This works, but in this example, the `WHERE` clause and `JOIN`s are simple enough.

But imagine a more complex example:

```
while 1=1 begin
  select
      -- Combine all phone numbers along with their type into one string
      @PhoneComp = @PhoneComp + ' ' + PhoneNo
        + case when PhTp is not null then '/' + PhTp end,
      @ListIx = p.ListIx
    from PhoneNumbers
    where
      CusId = @CusId and ListIx > @ListIx and
      ListIx = (select min(ListIx) from PhoneNumbers where CusId = @CusId and ListIx > @ListIx)
end
```

And even this is simplified, but I worry about the subqueries potentially getting too complex.

You see, in Sybase ASE, the following was possible:

```
while 1=1 begin
  select
      -- Combine all phone numbers along with their type into one string
      @PhoneComp = @PhoneComp + ' ' + PhoneNo
        + case when PhTp is not null then '/' + PhTp end,
      @ListIx = p.ListIx
    from PhoneNumbers
    where
      CusId = @CusId and ListIx > @ListIx
    having
      CusId = @CusId and ListIx > @ListIx and ListIx = min(ListIx)
end
```

Even though, when you *really* think about it, it doesn't make sense, yet you know what it means (and so fortunately does Sybase).  But that code get MS SQL Server to complain:

```
Column 'PhoneNumbers.CusId' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Column 'PhoneNumbers.ListIx' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

You may ask, why is the `WHERE` clause basically repeated in the `HAVING` clause?  This is because Sybase ASE ignores the `WHERE` clause when there is a `HAVING` clause.

For instance in Sybase ASE:

```
select
    ListIx, PhoneNo
  from PhoneNumbers
  where
    CusId = @CusId
  having
    ListIx=min(ListIx)
```

Will get all phone numbers that has the lowest ListIx, regardless of customer (`@CusId`).  Edit: I should mention that by adding `group by CusId` the result is as expected, but the fact that Sybase ASE even permits this is questionable.

I mention Sybase ASE here, because I am working on converting a lot of old Sybase ASE SQL code to work with MS SQL Server.  And while subqueries do work, I do wonder if I am missing some obvious solution.

Comment: Search around stackoverflow for ROW_NUMBER.   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY ListIx desc) r (..) where r = 1 (for MSSQL that is, for sybase join on subquery with min(ListIx) group by CustId)

Comment: @mxix: Wasn't Sybase 15.x supposed to have `ROW_NUMBER()`?  Still, while this is an interesting solution, I fear subqueries will be what I use for now to ensure the code works in both Sybase and MS SQL.

Comment: I don't really know Sybase. Just wanted to point out a cross DB solution. If sybase also has ROW_NUMBER give it a try, its a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the direct question

> what is the most elegant way to do this?

I would use `OUTER APPLY` on SQL Server:

```
select
    c.FirstName
    ,c.LastName
    ,pn.PhoneNo
from
    Customers c
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) PhoneNumbers.PhoneNo
        FROM PhoneNumbers
        WHERE PhoneNumbers.CusId = c.CusId
        ORDER BY PhoneNumbers.ListIx
    ) AS ph
```

If you need a code that works both on SQL Server and Sybase, that's a different story.

In my opinion, `OUTER APPLY` is the most elegant and efficient way. It also very clearly shows what you are after: for each customer we are looking for one phone number, that is the first in the list, when ordered by `ListIx`.

Here we should use `OUTER APPLY`, not `CROSS APPLY`, because it is possible that customer doesn't have any phone numbers. With `OUTER APPLY` the customer will be included in the result with NULL for the phone number. With `CROSS APPLY` such customer would not be included in the result.

Actually, it depends on what you really need, so `CROSS APPLY` may be the correct choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   PhoneNo
from (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY
                c.CusId 
             ORDER BY
                pn.ListIx DESC
        ) r,
        c.FirstName, 
        c.LastName, 
        pn.PhoneNo
    from Customers c
    left join PhoneNumbers pn on 
        c.CusId = pn.CusId
) T
where
    r = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will works in SQL Server:

```
select c.FirstName, c.LastName,
       (select top 1 pn.PhoneNo
        from PhoneNumbers pn
        where c.CusId = pn.CusId
        order by ListIx
       ) as phoneNo
from Customers c;
```

For both databases, I *think* this works:

```
select c.FirstName, c.LastName,
       (select PhoneNo
        from (select pn.PhoneNo, row_number() over (partition by CusId order by LIstIx) as seqnum
              from PhoneNumbers pn
              where c.CusId = pn.CusId
             ) t
        where seqnum = 1
       ) as phoneNo
from Customers c;
```

Of course, not all versions of Sybase support window functions.